# CSS issue: Top border not displaying in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

On my site, I'm using the JavaScript Tabifier to create tabs

In Firefox, the tabs have a top border (as desired).

In IE 6/7, the tabs do not have a top border, even though I have `border-top` defined for the appropriate CSS property (`ul.tabbernav li a`).

Any CSS ideas as to why Firefox has the top border but IE does not?

**UPDATE**

Per comment below, the page now w3c validates BUT I am still experiencing the CSS issue as originally outlined.

**UPATE 2**

Yes, I'm aware IE 6/7/8 does not support border-radius but I have removed that property and explicitly defined `border-top` and the border-top is still not displaying for IE 6/7.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to debug it while there are machine detectable errors in the HTML http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uptownelite.com%2Ffind%2F%3Fcity%3DDallas%2CTX&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 and CSS http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uptownelite.com%2Ffind%2F%3Fcity%3DDallas%2CTX&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en

Comment: All, I have fixed the errors that David Borward brought to my attention. The page now validates

Comment: If you're talking about the All/For Sale/etc tabs, in IE 8, the top border does show.

Comment: @Nick, yes, I'm talking about those tabs. Hmm, this must just be a IE 6/7 ... and not IE 8. Any ideas on how to fix IE 6/7?

Comment: Note, this problem is still not resolved based on the 1 answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add `margin-top:1px;` to `ul.tabbernav` or `padding-top:1px;` to `div.listingTabs`

I know this is an IE error but Firebug in FF can still help. If you inspect your ul or the div you will see the ul is outside of the display area of the parent div.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using curved borders. IE 6 and 7 don't support curved borders. I think IE 8 does.

Create an IE-specific stylesheet and change the way you create the borders here.

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

You can either display regular borders or remove the borders and create a background image to make it look like there are curved borders.

Comment: No curved borders in IE 8, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I am using curved borders but should IE still display the top border regardless?

Comment: It's displaying the left and right border just fine but not the top border.

Comment: Since it's not supported there's a high chance of everything breaking altogether. Try removing it a test if it's working

Comment: If you notice in the CSS for 'ul.tabbernav li a', I even explicitly tell IE to display the border-top and it's still not

Comment: @marcgg, I tested removing all 'radius' attributes and IE 6/7 still didn't display a border-top. Only left/right borders. Very strange

Comment: I see this: border-style: solid solid none, try changing it to border-style:solid;

Comment: @marcgg, where do you see border-style: solid solid none? what code line since when I do a search for that, I don't find it in my index.html

Comment: @marcgg (thanks in advance for your help so far ... hoping you can help pinpoint this problem)  :)

Comment: I see that on "ul.tabbernav li a" using firebug

Comment: I added "border-style:solid" to "ul.tabbernav li a" but in IE 6, that doesn't fix it. You can see it live at the link in the original post. Again, thanks for helping so far. We are getting close

Comment: It's working fine in IE7 now. I only have IE 7 here so I'm not sure how I can help you more.Try looking up if you have IE6 specific styles ( starting with _ )

Comment: oh nevermind it's not working in IE7 :\ I was looking it up in safari for some reason. I don't really have any more ideas here. triple check any IE specific things and border related styles

Comment: Nope, no ie hacks like using the underscore (_). Thanks marcgg for you're help. Hopefully someone else can figure it out. I'm at a loss

Comment: damn. well good luck with that, sorry I wasn't more helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the line-height for those. I had an extremely similar issue in ie7 once, except it did not show both the top and bottom borders. They were actually being cutoff.

```
line-height: 22px;
```

Not sure about the exact height that would work for you here, but try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got IE with which I can test at the moment; but is there a chance of the borders being outside of the height of the containing `div` (`.tabbernav`) and hidden with an `overflow` rule elsewhere?

On the off chance, you might want to try addding `overflow: visible` to the `.tabbernave` class. That or increasing it's height, and reducing the height of the `.tabbernave li`s.

Answer (score 0):

All offered solutions *did not* work for me in IE7, but this one did :-)

Seperate the sub-styles as follows:

```
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-color: red;
```

[I used the solution from this source](http://csscreator.com/node/30802#xcomment-135339)